# How to get X-RateLimit in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, http-status-code-429

I have been getting a 429 error, and want to find out the details. Sadly, python does not provide those automatically. So, how do I get the details?

Answer (score 0):

You can find details on the 429 error here:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find how to do that there.

Comment: 429 error means that you're exceeding the rate limits. E.g. You're using the discord API way to much in a small period of time. You should try to slow down your usage with sleep functions or try reduce the number of calls being made.